# get max value of x in relation of two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

in my data

```
data=structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    v2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), x = c(10L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 30L, 3L, 5L)), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
"x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

There are 3 variables. 
I need to get only those lines in relation to which X, has the max value.
For example. Take First category of v1 and  look in relation to which category v2 x has max value
It is

```
v1=1 and v2=1 x=10
```

Take second category of v1 and  look in relation to which category v2 x has max value
It is `v1=2 ,v2=3 x=30`

so desired output

```
v1  v2  x
1   1   10
2   3   30
```

How to do it?

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr);
data %>% group_by(v1) %>% slice(which.max(x))
` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, .SD[which.max(x)], keyby = v1]

   v1 v2  x
1:  1  1 10
2:  2  3 30
```

And for completeness an ugly base-R solution:

```
t(sapply(split(data, data[["v1"]]), function(s) s[which.max(s[["x"]]),]))
  v1 v2 x 
1 1  1  10
2 2  3  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  filter(x == max(x))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   v1 [2]
     v1    v2     x
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1    10
2     2     3    30
```